# Logging script commands and errors in linux

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, logging

2 part question,
I am running a script that executes a second script. 
I have it setup this way because I read  if I put a script in the `/etc/init.d` directory it will run it at start up.(true or false?)

I have tried adding `>> LoopTriggerLogging.log` at the end of each line but nothing comes out in the log file

So I have a first `script` as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

/var/www/Dev/LoopTrigger.sh

exit
```

This triggers the following `script` to run

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    # do some work
php /var/www/Dev/FindNearestDriverAndSendPush.php
php /var/www/Dev/ProcessCustomerPayment.php
php /var/www/Dev/ProcessDriversPayment.php
    # write to LoopTriggerLogging.log

    sleep 2                        # sleep and repeat
done
```

What I would like is to have the commands logged along with any errors. I have tried to read a little on this but get lost in the answers and what they are trying to tell the user. I am still new at this and learning, kindly give definition to any commands or options. I am open to a best practice scenario.

Also, with putting in the `etc/init.d` directory will this tell the script to run at start up? 
Is there a way to run this script without it taking up the command line because its an endless script?

My ultimate goal is to get the 3 `php` files to execute every 2 seconds with some sort of logging. 
I did some reading on Cron but seems it is not meant for this type of use case.

Ive also seen this:

`exec > logfile 2>&1`  (dont know what this does)

`set -x` makes bash print every command before executing it

`FOO=BAR`  (dont know what this means)

`echo $FOO`  (dont know what this means)

Answer (score 0):

> if I put a script in the /etc/init.d directory it will run it at start
>   up.(true or false)

**True**. If you put a script in init.d then that script will run for every startup.

> My ultimate goal is to get the 3 php files to execute every 2 seconds

You are using the correct way of running it approx every 2sec depending upon the time your php script takes to run. Crontab runs after a minimum of one minute so that would not an option.

> I have tried adding >> LoopTriggerLogging.log at the end of each line
>   but nothing comes out in the log file

You can use `/var/www/Dev/LoopTrigger.sh >> LoopTriggerLogging.log` in your first script so that whenever it runs it will

1. Create a file for the first time and append the content from the next time.
2. Push all the logs of the second script into the file.

Note: As logs will keep on appending to the single file, this file will become very huge at some point of time so make sure your handle it well.

Comment: This method is not creating any data in the log file
is there a way to log only errors from the script?
Also, if I manually execute the first script from the '/etc/init.d' directory, can I exit the terminal and it still run as it would on start-up? Because it takes over my shell terminal